# If cohomology theory corresponds to intersection theory, valuation theory corresponds to -?

Tags: soft-question, cohomology, intersection-theory

This is a meta question I asked myself. Cohomology theory is dual to an intersection theory. Is there anything valuation theory corresponds to in general?

For instance, McMullen's polytope algebra is dual to the stable intersection of tropical cycles.